# Combine width media query and JQuery Scroll top

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries

I am new to jQuery and have successfully implemented this code which makes my header stick when the user has scrolled down 100px

However when using media queries, I have reduced the height to 80px at a `max-width` of 650px and therefore, for 650px and under, I need the jQuery to fire at 80px scroll not 100px.

Is there a way to combine media queries with jQuery?

My jQuery so far is this:

```
 jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
        if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
            jQuery('#masthead').addClass('fixed-header');
        }
        else {
            jQuery('#masthead').removeClass('fixed-header');
        }
    });
```

CSS

```
.fixed-header {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; 
}
```

I had a crack at it and tried this:

```
    if ($(window).width() >= 651) { 

        
                                    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
                                        if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
                                            jQuery('#masthead').addClass('fixed-header');
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            jQuery('#masthead').removeClass('fixed-header');
                                        }
                                    });
                                }


else {


                                jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
                                    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= 80) {
                                        jQuery('#masthead').addClass('fixed-header');
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        jQuery('#masthead').removeClass('fixed-header');
                                    }
                                });
                             }   

}
```

And

```
if ( pageWidth > 651 ) {
    
                        jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
                                if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
                                    jQuery('#masthead').addClass('fixed-header');
                                }
                                else {
                                    jQuery('#masthead').removeClass('fixed-header');
                                }
                            });
                        
                        }

else {


                        jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
                            if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= 80) {
                                jQuery('#masthead').addClass('fixed-header');
                            }
                            else {
                                jQuery('#masthead').removeClass('fixed-header');
                            }
                        });

                    }
}
```

But neither work.

**Edited

I have made a JSFiddle here
https://jsfiddle.net/shereewalker/2r8Lcn7j/36/

I intend to ensure that the second header sticks when it reaches the top, which currently functions as I want. But when I reduce the height of the top header for 650px and below to 80px, there is a jump as the sticky position on the second header still applies itself at `scrollTop` 100px.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I'm happy to solve this for you, if you create a JSFiddle with easy reproducibility.

Comment: Hi there, that's great thanks. I have made a fiddle and added it to the original question

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `position: sticky`?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights Honestly, I didn't know about position sticky, but I tried adding it with top:0 and it did not work?

Comment: Added an answer with a working example @MrToad

Answer (score 3):

You can use `position: sticky` instead of relying on jQuery:

```css
.content-body {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.header-top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
}

#masthead {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fbc957;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.fixed-header {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width:650px) {
  .header-top,
  #masthead {
    height: 80px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content-body">
  <div class="header-top">
    <p>I have a logo in this banner</p>
  </div>

  <div class="menu-wrapper" id="masthead">
    <p>There is a secondary logo in this banner</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, for some reason, I could not get it to work, despite clearly being able to see it working in the snippit? The sticky position just would not take. I would have split the bounty if I could but the other answer worked and so I awarded it to them. Thank you though

Answer (score 2):

You can easily solve this by measuring the height of masthead and act according to it:

```
function getMastheadHeight() {
    return jQuery('#masthead').height();
}

jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= getMastheadHeight()) {
        jQuery('#masthead').addClass('fixed-header');
    }
    else {
        jQuery('#masthead').removeClass('fixed-header');
    }
});


jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= getMastheadHeight()) {
        jQuery('#masthead:not(.menu-absolute)').addClass('sticky-mob-menu');
    }
    else {
        jQuery('#masthead:not(.menu-absolute)').removeClass('sticky-mob-menu');
    }
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/moyztg0d/1/

In short: The answer is yes, you can combine jQuery and CSS. Please try the fiddle above. I changed the media query for ease of testability, but you can change it back without issues. You can also use CSS for this particular problem, as Daniel Knights pointed out (upvoted that answer), but for the cases when there is no CSS solution, it's worth to remember that you can programmatically solve these issues as well.